# How to call a linux command line program in parallel with python

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, subprocess, pool

I have a command-line program which runs on single core. It takes an input file, does some calculations, and returns several files which I need to parse to store the produced output.
I have to call the program several times changing the input file. To speed up the things I was thinking parallelization would be useful.
Until now I have performed this task calling every run separately within a loop with the subprocess module.

I wrote a script which creates a new working folder on every run and than calls the execution of the program whose output is directed to that folder and returns some data which I need to store. My question is, how can I adapt the following code, found [here](https://alexandra-zaharia.github.io/posts/run-python-script-as-subprocess-with-multiprocessing/), to execute my script always using the indicated amount of CPUs, and storing the output.
Note that each run has a unique running time.
Here the mentioned code:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm

NUMBER_OF_TASKS = 4
progress_bar = tqdm(total=NUMBER_OF_TASKS)

def work(sec_sleep):
    command = ['python', 'worker.py', sec_sleep]
    subprocess.call(command)


def update_progress_bar(_):
    progress_bar.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(NUMBER_OF_TASKS)

    for seconds in [str(x) for x in range(1, NUMBER_OF_TASKS + 1)]:
         pool.apply_async(work, (seconds,), callback=update_progress_bar)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely clear what your issue is. I have some recommendations for improvement below, but you seem to claim on the page that you link to that everything works as expected and I don't see anything *very* wrong with the code as long as you are running on Linux.

Since the `subprocess.call` method is already creating a new process, you should just be using multithreading to invoke your worker function, `work`. But had you been using multiprocessing and your platform was one that used the *spawn* method to create new processes (such as Windows), then having the creation of the progress bar outside of the `if __name__ = '__main__':` block would have resulted in the creation of 4 additional progress bars that did nothing. Not good! So for portability it would have been best to move its creation to inside the `if __name__ = '__main__':` block.

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from tqdm import tqdm


def work(sec_sleep):
    command = ['python', 'worker.py', sec_sleep]
    subprocess.call(command)


def update_progress_bar(_):
    progress_bar.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUMBER_OF_TASKS = 4

    progress_bar = tqdm(total=NUMBER_OF_TASKS)

    pool = ThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_TASKS)

    for seconds in [str(x) for x in range(1, NUMBER_OF_TASKS + 1)]:
         pool.apply_async(work, (seconds,), callback=update_progress_bar)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**Note: If your *worker.py* program prints to the console, it will mess up the progress bar (the progress bar will be re-written repeatedly on multiple lines).**

Have you considered instead importing `worker.py` (some refactoring of that code might be necessary) instead of invoking a new Python interpreter to execute it (in this case you *would* want to be explicitly using multiprocessing). On Windows this might not save you anything since a new Python interpreter would be executed for each new process anyway, but this could save you on Linux:

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from worker import do_work
from tqdm import tqdm


def update_progress_bar(_):
    progress_bar.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUMBER_OF_TASKS = 4
    progress_bar = tqdm(total=NUMBER_OF_TASKS)
    pool = Pool(NUMBER_OF_TASKS)

    for seconds in [str(x) for x in range(1, NUMBER_OF_TASKS + 1)]:
         pool.apply_async(do_work, (seconds,), callback=update_progress_bar)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```